# How to detect a consensus is BFT or not?

Tags: consensus, terminology, byzantine-fault-tolerance

- Can we divide consensus algorithms into BFT (Byzantine Fault
  Tolerant) and non-BFT ?
- If so, How to detect a consensus is BFT or non-BFT ?
- Is there any non-BFT consensus algorithm example ?